# Nested ui-router state without nested view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a nested state without a nested view. Suppose I have this setup:

```
App.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "/index",
       templateUrl: "views/home.html",
        controller: "MainController",
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Home'
        }
    })
    .state('About', {
        url: "/about",
        templateUrl: "views/about.html",
        controller: "AboutController",
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'About',
            parent: 'index'
        }
    })
    .state('us', {
        url: "/us",
        templateUrl: "views/us.html",
        controller: "UsController",
        parent: 'about',
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Us'
        }
    })
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /home
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index");

});
```

When I visit `/about`, I get the about page. When I visit `/about/us`, I still get the about page with the us page loaded in the `ui-view` of the about page. However, what I would like to do is load the about page on `/about` and just the us page on `/us`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is possible. What we have to use, is the absolute naming. State defintion would look like this:

```
.state('us', {
    url: "/us",
    views : {
      "@" : { // here we are using absolute name targeting
        templateUrl: "views/us.html",
        controller: "UsController", 
      },
    }
    parent: 'about',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'Us'
    }
})
```

See doc:

#### [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of **`viewname@statename`**, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. contact.item. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.
>
> For example, the previous example could also be written as:

```
.state('report',{
    views: {
      'filters@': { },
      'tabledata@': { },
      'graph@': { }
    }
})
```

So as documentation shows, we can use absolute naming. In our case, we will target root state which nams is string empty (index.html) - the part after delimiter @. And it is unnamed view - string Empty before @. That is why we use:

```
    views : {
      "@" : {
```

*NOTE: behind the scenes, `UI-Router` used this for state `us`:*

```
    views : {
      "@about" : {
```

There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ROmQSaVgTKNxyEiGR25P?p=preview), with these states in action:

```
// States
$stateProvider

  .state('index', {
    url: "/index",
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
  .state('about', {
    url: "/about",
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
  .state('us', {
    url: "/us",
    parent: "about",
    views : {
      '@': {
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      },
    }
  })
```

Check it in [action](http://plnkr.co/edit/ROmQSaVgTKNxyEiGR25P?p=preview) that if the 'us' is a state name the ui-sref="us" will properly navigate to `'/about/us'`.

Comment: Thanks! There's one more question though. Before this, I always used `ui-sref='about.us'`, but that doesn't work now. What should I change it into now?

Comment: Yes! This is because we have to use a **state name** and it is **'us'**. So only way is to use `ui-sref='us'`. OR, we can use different way to express the child state. Instead of attribute `parent : "About"` we can use implicit parent definition like `.state('about.us'` ... now about is parent again, but the state name contains both... parent and child... does it help?

Comment: But if I use `ui-sref='us'` it links to `/about`

Comment: I updated answer with a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ROmQSaVgTKNxyEiGR25P?p=preview) which should show how the ui-sref="us" is now working...

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just because a state shares part of the url doesn't mean it has to be a parent/child relationship. Just set the `us` state's url to `/about/us` and don't give it a parent.

```
App.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "/index",
        templateUrl: "views/home.html",
        controller: "MainController",
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Home'
        }
    })
    .state('About', {
        url: "/about",
        templateUrl: "views/about.html",
        controller: "AboutController",
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'About',
            parent: 'index'
        }
    })
    .state('us', {
        url: "/about/us",
        templateUrl: "views/us.html",
        controller: "UsController",
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Us'
        }
    })
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /home
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index");
});
```